# django1.8 F expressions and string subsets

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I have the following model called `sheetinfo`:

```
class Sheetinfo(models.Model):
    sheet_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    group_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,default = 'xx')
```

I want to update all of the `group_id` to be a subset of the `sheet_id` string -
specifically:

```
group_id = sheet_id[19:-6]
```

I tried the following using F expressions
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F

```
def fix_group():
    qs = Sheetinfo.objects.all()
    qs.update(group_num=F('sheet_id')[19:-6])
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
'F' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I can do the following which works but is SLOWWWW (10+ min per 1M rows)

```
qs = Sheetinfo.objects.all()
for s in qs:
    group_id_str = s.sheet_id
    s.group_id = str(group_id_str)[19:-6]
    s.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `F()` support is limited to numeric operations with the following operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%` and `**`.

Comment: ah crap. Well sounds like I need to chug through and set a script to run overnight. Thanks for your help!